# Thread safe Hash Set

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, synchronization, mutex

I have several threads picking up jobs to process.  To prevent jobs from picking up the same job as another, the jobs are coordinated with the class below:

```
public class CurrentlyProcessingCollection
{
    private readonly HashSet<string> _currentlyProcessing = new HashSet<string>();
    private readonly object _myLock = new object();

    public bool TryAdd(string id)
    {
        return SynchronisedContext(
            () =>
                {
                    return _currentlyProcessing.Add(id)
                });
    }

    public void Remove(string id)
    {
        SynchronisedContext(() => _currentlyProcessingFiles.Remove(id));
    }

    private T SynchronisedContext<T>(Func<T> function)
    {
        lock (_myLock)
        {
            return function();
        }
    }
}
```

If `TryAdd(id)` returns false, then the process will ignore the job and move onto the next.  Once a job if finished it will remove the job from the list.

Unfortunately, this isn't what's always happening and I'm occasionally getting jobs processed twice (very bad).  The problem *could* be elsewhere in the code, each thread decides whether to rub the job with the following code:

```
var jobs = GetJobs();

foreach (var job in jobs)
{
    var tryAdd = CURRENT_FILES.TryAdd(job);


    if (tryAdd)
    {
        ImportFile(job);
    }
}
```

There is the `Remove(job)` method, I'm looking to see if there's any way that could be called prematurely, it's unlikely though as the jobs are files which are moved to another directory after processing.

Any suggestions on how `TryAdd(id)` might be returning true more than once?

Am I using the synchronisation lock correctly?

Comment: You need to provide more code, error is not here

Comment: I'd also suggest you to remove that SynchronisedContext method, which adds no value and just bloats your code. Just do lock (_mylock) {...} instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is correct. Source: me.

The problem is elsewhere. My guess is that the following sequence happens:

1. Job added
2. Job done and removed
3. The same job id added. Here, you expected `Add` to return false but the removal is already done.

If this is true you need to maintain another set with completed job IDs.

Comment: I think you're right.  Thanks for checking the `CurrentlyProcessingCollection` though.